# In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), when using "Copy Diagram to Clipboard", how can you get it to include column names?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), right-clicking on a database diagram and choosing "Copy Diagram to Clipboard" results in a image of the diagram that is missing the table's column names.  The table names, outlines of the tables, and relationships between tables are all visible, but the table's column names are not visible.  Needless to say, the column names are visible in the actual diagram.

In SSMS, when using "Copy Diagram to Clipboard", how can you get it to include column names?

---

I have tried the newest version of SSMS (v18.4 but also a few of the older versions).

Answer (score 7):

In my case this only happened when I used SSMS on a machine which I RDPed to. When pasting the copied diagram directly to e.g. Paint on the same machine, the diagram looks perfect! And then from paint I could properly copy&paste it from the remote to my local machine…

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the problem exists with 17.9.1 and 18.4.  Pasting the image in any application yields no column names.  Zooming in or zooming out doesn't appear to make a difference.  Moving to the top left corner or lower right corner doesn't make a difference.  Annoying!